# Mocking static method throws error with parameters

Tags: java, testing, mockito

I have custom Log4j2 appender:

```
    @Plugin(
            name = "MyAppender",
            category = "Core",
            elementType = Appender.ELEMENT_TYPE)
    public class MyAppender extends AbstractAppender {
    
        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MyAppender.class);
        private final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
    
    
        private MyAppender(final String name, final Layout<? extends Serializable> layout ) {
            super(name, null, layout, false, Property.EMPTY_ARRAY);
        }
    
    
        @Override
        public void append(LogEvent event) {
           ....
        }
    
        @PluginFactory
        public static MyAppender createAppender(
                @PluginAttribute("name") String name,
                @PluginElement("Layout") Layout<? extends Serializable> layout){
            if (layout == null) {
                layout = PatternLayout.createDefaultLayout();
            }
            return new MyAppender(name, layout);
        }
}
```

And i want to mock the `createAppenderMethod`:

```
 try (MockedStatic<MyAppender> mocked = mockStatic(MyAppender.class)) {
            MyAppender appender = Mockito.mock(MyAppender.class);
            mocked.when(() -> MyAppender.createAppender("myAppender", Mockito.any(Layout.class))).thenReturn(appender);
              ....
        }
```

However this trows

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue:  MyAppender
> cannot be returned by toString() toString() should return String

I tried to implement `toString()` method but the error remains the same.

If u use
 `mocked.when(() -> MyAppender.createAppender("myAppender", Mockito.anyObject())).thenReturn(appender);`

then i recieve:

> org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.MissingMethodInvocationException:
> when() requires an argument which has to be 'a method call on a mock'.
> For example:
> when(mock.getArticles()).thenReturn(articles);

Why is this happening? What is the correct way to mock this? So far this way of mocking static methods worked for me

Answer (score -1):

As per my understanding mocking static methods are not good to follow as it challenges the design level decision. Kindly someone guide me if am wrong.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).